# How to remove space when combining variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Would like to know how to remove space when combining string variables in below code. Cause when I count the length of `$myname`, it will also include the space length

```
$myname = $firstname + " " + $lastname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use replace and regex to replace spaces with nothing before you do the length function.
Last $myname is just to prove we didn't actually remove spaces in the variable while getting the length.

```
$LastName = "Smith"
$FirstName = "John"
$myname = $Firstname + " " + $Lastname
$myname
($myname -replace "\s","").length
$myname
```

Output

```
John Smith
9
John Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the two variables without *space between*, just use

```
$myname = $firstname  + $lastname
```

Or a format string:

```
$myname = '{0}{1}' -f $firstname, $lastname
```

If you want to remove the spaces at the *start and end*, use

```
$myname = ('{0}{1}' -f $firstname, $lastname).Trim()
```

You could also use `TrimEnd` to *only trim the spaces at the end* of the string or `TrimStart` to only trim the *spaces at the start*. If you want to get rid of *all spaces* in the string, you could use a `regex`:

```
$myname = ('{0}{1}' -f $firstname, $lastname) -replace '\s'
```

Comment: Thanks jisaak. Great info. What i mean is i want to use this format **$myname = $firstname + " " + $lastname**. But when i use the Length function as below, it will include to count the space as well. How to not include the space when using the length function as below    **$myname.Length**

Comment: Can you provide an example with the firstname and lastname and the desired output?